# asp.net MVC jquery page transitions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, uislider, css-transitions

I'm building a web application using ASP.Net MVC 3, Razor and jQuery.  I want to use masterpages (`_layout.cshtml`) and have a slide-in / slide-out page transition.  I know how to do it using jQuery mobile but I want to do it without jQuery Mobile.  I'm thinking I can do it with just two `div`'s.  Anybody have any experience or sample code etc..?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. If you include jQuery UI, you can create a container that contains the divs (or really whatever block level elements you prefer), and then specify:

`$("#first-element").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000, function(){ 
    $("#next-element").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
});`

This is not a fully baked example, but might be enough to get you started.

The jQuery UI docs might be helpful too. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/)